# Failure to make test suite pass golang "sayHello() used as value"

Tags: go

I'm trying to make this test suite pass through the command prompt (hello-world_test.go):

```
package helloworld

import "testing"

func TestHelloWorld(t *testing.T) {
    output := sayHello()
    if "Hello, World!" != output {
        t.Fatalf("output: %s\nexpected: Hello,World!", output)
    }
}
```

my code is as follows (helloworld.go):

```
package helloworld

import "fmt"

func sayHello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")

}
```

and the error code through the command prompt is:

```
C:\Users\Troy\exercism\go\hello-world\go test -v
# _/C_/Users/Troy/exercism/go/hello-world
.\hello-world_test.go:6: sayHello() used as value
FAIL    _/C_/Users/Troy/exercism/go/hello-world [build failed]
```

Comment: `sayHello` does not return anything, and yet you capture its output to `output`.

Answer (score -1):

I have developed (for this kind of unit test) [`godbg.Out()` and `godbg.Err()`](https://github.com/VonC/godbg/blob/aaf5d23b02f438b6d01009bd600f704856da93a2/godbg.go#L29-L57), two `io.Writer` which, by default, are `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr`.

That means I no longer use `fmt.Println("Hello, World!")`.

Instead I do:

```
fmt.Fprintln(Out(), "Hello, World!")
```

That allows me, when I want to unit test that output (and not having the unit test own output filled with `fmt.Println` results), to **change the default `io.Writer`** with ones dedicated for that test, using the [`pdbg.SetBuffer()`](https://github.com/VonC/godbg/blob/aaf5d23b02f438b6d01009bd600f704856da93a2/godbg.go#L66-L77) function.

That way, [my test becomes](https://github.com/VonC/godbg/blob/aaf5d23b02f438b6d01009bd600f704856da93a2/godbg_test.go#L54-L65):

```
    Convey("Test custom buffer reset on global pdbg", func() {
        SetBuffers(nil)
        fmt.Fprint(Out(), "test content")
        So(OutString(), ShouldEqual, `test content`)
        fmt.Fprint(Err(), "err1 cerr")
        So(ErrString(), ShouldEqual, `err1 cerr`)
        ResetIOs()
        fmt.Fprint(Out(), "test2 content2")
        So(OutString(), ShouldEqual, `test2 content2`)
        fmt.Fprint(Err(), "err2 cerr2")
        So(ErrString(), ShouldEqual, `err2 cerr2`)
    })
```

I can now test outputs done on stdout or stderr by replacing (during the unit test only) those writers with my own.

Notes:

- I use the **[goconvey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey)** unit test framework here.
- the design is still in progress. I might move those writer functions in their own package later on.

Comment: You know, that `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr` are *variables* that you can overwrite with your own readers and writers?

Comment: @FUZxxl I prefered initially not modifying them, but I will certainly simplify the current design.

Comment: I mean, if what you want to do is to observe what goes through `Stdout` and what actually goes out there doesn't matter, this sounds like a pretty good approach.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently all i had to do to get the original test suite to pass was define the `sayHello()` function as a string, and return its value `"Hello, World!`. Also, i made lines 3 and 6 comments, as they do not affect the code directly:

```
package helloworld

//import "fmt" 

func sayHello() string {
    //fmt.Println("Hello, World!") 
    return "Hello, World!"
}
```

do the comments make the style of the code "tacky"?